# Change CSS attribute of empty inputs selected by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am missing something here. Seems like an easy question. I have this:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required />
  <input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" required />
  ...
</form>
```

I want this function to work:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {

    var fields = $('.form-control');
    _.each(fields, function(field) {
        if( field.value == "" ) {
            field.css("background","#FFB6B5");
        }
    });

});
```

I get `undefined is not a function` on the line:

```
field.css("background","#FFB6B5");
```

Is like the `field` is not an element. Why this is happening?

Comment: What's with `_.each`? Any reason you're not using jQuery's `$.each`?

Comment: Good point! I am new with this, so I was mixing up jQuery and underscore.js, apparently. Thanks!

Comment: Hey as long as it works :)

Comment: I would suggest that you change the class and define your css in a stylesheet instead of setting inline styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your code `field` refers to underlying DOM element and [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) is a jQuery function. Thus you need to use jQuery object.

*Use*

```
$(field).css("background","#FFB6B5");
```

You can use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

> Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.

*Example*

```
$('.form-control').each(function( index ) {
    if(this.value == ""){
        $(this).css("background","#FFB6B5");
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {

    $('.form-control').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "" ) {
            $(this).css("background","#FFB6B5");
        } else {
            $(this).css("background","#FFF");
        } 
    });

});
```